# How to take only last two rows of postgres with group by function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a task table which is like this

```
id      timestamp                               event_type
2           "2018-12-17 09:25:05"               open
2           "2018-12-17 09:26:05"               cancel
2           "2018-12-17 09:27:05"               open
2           "2018-12-17 09:29:05"               closed
3           "2018-12-17 09:25:05"               open
3           "2018-12-17 09:28:05"               closed
```

and I need to get the data based on difference between open and closed event but only last open and closed event and not in between.
For e.g. task 2 is cancelled in between so the difference between only last 2 ('open','close') event needs to be calculated

output is something like

```
Task    Time taken
2       2:00
3       3:00
```

I checked some array_agg functions but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ee0be23e6a7351365fe685ad830b029a)

```
SELECT 
    id,
    MAX(ts) FILTER (WHERE event_type = 'closed') -
    MAX(ts) FILTER (WHERE event_type = 'open') as time_taken
FROM
    events
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select id, 
  DATE_PART(
        'minute',
        max(case when event_type='open' then timestamp end)::timestamp -
        max(case when event_type='closed' then timestamp end)::timestamp
       )
from tablename
group by id
```

Comment: There is no datediff in Postgres

Answer (score 0):

I think `lag()` is a safer solution:

```
select id, (timestamp - prev_open_timestamp)
from (select e.*,
             max(timestamp) filter (where event_type = 'open') over (partition by id order by timestamp) as prev_open_timestamp
      from events e
     ) e
where event_type = 'closed';
```

This will work even if there is an `open` after the `close`.